# App crashes when i try to getText from EditText

Tags: android

I don't know why does it crash, when i try to set the aaa and bbb strings to an exact value like the code i commented, it worsk perectly but when i try to get text from my edittexts it chrashes...

```
 EditText text1;
 EditText text2;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Remove title bar
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    //Remove notification bar
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    OpemM = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.battlefield);
    OpemM.start();
    gm1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.gm1);

    gm3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.gm3);
    am1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.am1);
    am2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.am2);
    am3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.am3);
    o3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.o3);
    text1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.t1);
    text2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.t2);

}

public void OnASD(View sender)
{
    /*String aaa = "aaa";
    String bbb = "bbb";*/
    String aaa =text1.getText().toString().trim();
    String bbb =text2.getText().toString().trim();

    Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(Menu.this, OnASameDevice.class);
     myIntent1.putExtra("player1", aaa);
     myIntent1.putExtra("player2", bbb);
     startActivity(myIntent1);
     finish();

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/pozadina" >

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/am1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
    android:background="@drawable/dugme1"
    android:onClick="next"
    android:text="@string/am1" />

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/am3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"


    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
    android:background="@drawable/dugme1"
    android:onClick="quit"
    android:text="@string/am3" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

game_menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="@drawable/pozadina">


<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/player1"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/t1"
    android:text="  "
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/player2"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/t2"
    android:text="  "
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>



<Button
    android:id="@+id/gm1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/dugme1"
    android:onClick="OnASD" 
    android:text="@string/gm1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/gm3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
    android:background="@drawable/dugme1"
    android:onClick="back"
    android:text="@string/gm3" />
```

Logs:

```
06-15 16:51:10.879: W/ApplicationPackageManager(17269): getCSCPackageItemText()
06-15 16:51:11.060: D/dalvikvm(17269): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 93K, 35% free 17209K/26192K, paused 16ms, total 17ms
06-15 16:51:11.130: I/dalvikvm-heap(17269): Grow heap (frag case) to 57.318MB for 38455036-byte allocation
06-15 16:51:11.260: I/Adreno-EGL(17269): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:381>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (CL3869936)
06-15 16:51:11.260: I/Adreno-EGL(17269): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 17.01.11.SPL
06-15 16:51:11.260: I/Adreno-EGL(17269): Build Date: 01/17/14 Fri
06-15 16:51:11.260: I/Adreno-EGL(17269): Local Branch: 
06-15 16:51:11.260: I/Adreno-EGL(17269): Remote Branch: 
06-15 16:51:11.260: I/Adreno-EGL(17269): Local Patches: 
06-15 16:51:11.260: I/Adreno-EGL(17269): Reconstruct Branch: 
06-15 16:51:11.300: D/OpenGLRenderer(17269): Enabling debug mode 0
06-15 16:51:16.275: W/ApplicationPackageManager(17269): getCSCPackageItemText()
06-15 16:51:16.335: D/dalvikvm(17269): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 19K, 15% free 54800K/63748K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
06-15 16:51:16.375: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(17269): native_setup
06-15 16:51:16.375: V/MediaPlayer(17269): constructor
06-15 16:51:16.375: V/MediaPlayer(17269): setListener
06-15 16:51:16.385: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(17269): setDataSourceFD: fd 56
06-15 16:51:16.385: V/MediaPlayer(17269): setDataSource(56, 4098303, 7988106)
06-15 16:51:16.385: V/MediaPlayer(17269): message received msg=8, ext1=0, ext2=0
06-15 16:51:16.385: V/MediaPlayer(17269): notify(8, 0, 0) callback on disconnected mediaplayer
06-15 16:51:16.405: V/MediaPlayer(17269): setVideoSurfaceTexture
06-15 16:51:16.405: V/MediaPlayer(17269): prepare
06-15 16:51:16.405: V/MediaPlayer(17269): message received msg=200, ext1=973, ext2=0
06-15 16:51:16.405: W/MediaPlayer(17269): info/warning (973, 0)
06-15 16:51:16.405: V/MediaPlayer(17269): callback application
06-15 16:51:16.405: V/MediaPlayer(17269): back from callback
06-15 16:51:16.405: V/MediaPlayer(17269): message received msg=5, ext1=0, ext2=0
06-15 16:51:16.405: V/MediaPlayer(17269): New video size 0 x 0
06-15 16:51:16.405: V/MediaPlayer(17269): callback application
06-15 16:51:16.405: V/MediaPlayer(17269): back from callback
06-15 16:51:16.405: V/MediaPlayer(17269): message received msg=1, ext1=0, ext2=0
06-15 16:51:16.405: V/MediaPlayer(17269): prepared
06-15 16:51:16.405: V/MediaPlayer(17269): signal application thread
06-15 16:51:16.405: V/MediaPlayer(17269): callback application
06-15 16:51:16.405: V/MediaPlayer(17269): back from callback
06-15 16:51:16.405: V/MediaPlayer(17269): prepare complete - status=0
06-15 16:51:16.405: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(17269): start
06-15 16:51:16.405: V/MediaPlayer(17269): start
06-15 16:51:16.475: V/MediaPlayer(17269): message received msg=6, ext1=0, ext2=0
06-15 16:51:16.475: V/MediaPlayer(17269): Received MEDIA_STARTED
06-15 16:51:16.475: V/MediaPlayer(17269): callback application
06-15 16:51:16.475: V/MediaPlayer(17269): back from callback
06-15 16:51:16.485: I/MediaPlayer(17269): Don't send intent. msg.arg1 = 0, msg.arg2 = 0
06-15 16:51:16.485: E/MediaPlayer(17269): Should have subtitle controller already set
06-15 16:51:16.525: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(17269): getCurrentPosition: 0 (msec)
06-15 16:51:16.525: V/MediaPlayer(17269): isPlaying: 1
06-15 16:51:16.525: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(17269): isPlaying: 1
06-15 16:51:26.855: D/AndroidRuntime(17269): Shutting down VM
06-15 16:51:26.855: W/dalvikvm(17269): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41879da0)
06-15 16:51:26.875: E/AndroidRuntime(17269): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-15 16:51:26.875: E/AndroidRuntime(17269): Process: com.JMS.sinktheship, PID: 17269
06-15 16:51:26.875: E/AndroidRuntime(17269): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
06-15 16:51:26.875: E/AndroidRuntime(17269):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3969)
06-15 16:51:26.875: E/AndroidRuntime(17269):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633)
06-15 16:51:26.875: E/AndroidRuntime(17269):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19330)
06-15 16:51:26.875: E/AndroidRuntime(17269):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
06-15 16:51:26.875: E/AndroidRuntime(17269):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-15 16:51:26.875: E/AndroidRuntime(17269):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
06-15 16:51:26.875: E/AndroidRuntime(17269):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
06-15 16:51:26.875: E/AndroidRuntime(17269):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-15 16:51:26.875: E/AndroidRuntime(17269):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-15 16:51:26.875: E/AndroidRuntime(17269):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
06-15 16:51:26.875: E/AndroidRuntime(17269):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
06-15 16:51:26.875: E/AndroidRuntime(17269):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-15 16:51:26.875: E/AndroidRuntime(17269): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-15 16:51:26.875: E/AndroidRuntime(17269):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-15 16:51:26.875: E/AndroidRuntime(17269):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-15 16:51:26.875: E/AndroidRuntime(17269):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3964)
06-15 16:51:26.875: E/AndroidRuntime(17269):    ... 11 more
06-15 16:51:26.875: E/AndroidRuntime(17269): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-15 16:51:26.875: E/AndroidRuntime(17269):    at com.JMS.sinktheship.Menu.OnASD(Menu.java:83)
06-15 16:51:26.875: E/AndroidRuntime(17269):    ... 14 more
06-15 16:51:29.087: I/Process(17269): Sending signal. PID: 17269 SIG: 9
```

Comment: String aaa =text1.getText().toString().trim();

Comment: show your activity_main.xml

Comment: post layout file not manifest file.

Comment: no. This is manifest file

Comment: activity_main.xml file located at layout folder

Comment: sorry my mistake... it isn't activity main it is the game menu... i change the content view on a button click... just didn't want to post irrelevant stuff

Comment: @Nikola is the posted xml name `activity_main.xml`??

Comment: @Nikola `text1` is null. check if you have `EditText` with the id `t1` in `activity_main.xml`. If not that's a mistake

Comment: @Raghunandan My activity on create sets content view on an activitymain.xml then i have a button that sets contentview on game_menu.xml, i posted game_menu.xml and there is EditText with id t1....

Comment: @Nikola then your design itself is wrong in the first place. Don't set layout twice to the same activity

Comment: @Raghunandan you think that causes the problem ?

Comment: @Raghunandan i didn't have any problem with all other stuff

Comment: @Nikola yes it does. and that is the cause

Comment: @Nikola could you pls post `activity_main.xml`

Answer (score 2):

hey Nikola i think your design it self is wrong one Activity can refer only one xml file. if you want to change the xml for same activity you need to inflate it during runtime. at your case copy your all textview's and edit text from game_menu.xml and paste it in your activity_main.xml i think this will work. Check out your activity you are using setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); which does not contain the editText which you are acessing. So i think that's the reason you are getting error.

Comment: that's good see. Finally you got the Solution. if you like my answer then follow the way to accept it.(Not mandatory if U want!!!)

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
text1.getText() or text1
```

is null. So

```
text1.getText().toString()
```

gives NullPointerException.

Comment: try to experiment. Set text in XML another than empty String, or delete your <requestFocus />, or delete setText attribute at all and so on

Comment: @Kalpazan getText() will not return null Can check the source code for confirmation. its definitely `text1` that's null

Comment: @Nikola why? Its because the EditText `text1` is not initialized properly. WHy? check the activity_main.xml

Comment: @Kalpazan `getText()` will never be null. You are wrong

Comment: Yes to xmls on one activity was the  problem, thanks.